# Proper Bulma setup in Angular

Tags: angular, installation, bulma

I'm trying to build a logistics system using Angular and Bulma for my project. I'm not entirely sure on how to set it up properly as I will need to add all the necessary Bulma files to assets and angular.json. Can you guide me on which files to import properly?

I have already installed Bulma via npm and added it to styles in the angular.json file.

Thank you

Comment: Does this work for you: https://scotch.io/courses/build-your-first-angular-website/adding-bulma-css-to-an-angular-app

Comment: Yeah, it does. Thank you